# Publish Gulp destination files with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: gulp, publish, visual-studio-2015

In the new Visual Studio 2015 and the Web Essentials plugin, they've removed the function to compile certain files like Less files. Instead they suggest to use Gulp tasks.

While I applaud this decision and understand how to configure Gulp to compile the Less files, but because this is not an ASP.NET 5 application, the new files are not automatically added to the project and as such do not get copied when using the Publish function of VS2015.

As I see it the only way to get these file to copy is to manually add them to the project. This seems a but counter intuitive, if you create a task to compile **/*.less you have to look in your entire project to find the generated css files and add them all manually.

Am I just doing something wrong or is this just the way it works now?

Answer (score 6):

Don't add the files manually, it is pretty easy to add them with a target in your project file. This is how we do it and we also use the gulp-rev package which modifies our filename dynamically (so they will not be cached by a browser). Here is how our BeforeBuild target from our .csproj file looks like:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="BeforeBuild.bat" WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" />
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="Scripts\Output\**\*.js" />
        <Content Include="Content\**\output\**\*.css" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

And in our case when we publish all the generated js files from Scripts\Output\all_folders\ will get published too even though they are not in the csproj (and the same for the generated css files)

Comment: What does the BuildBefore.bat file do? Run the Gulp tasks? I guess we're going to have to change the way we work, but we were kinda used to just adding a new .less file (wherever in the project) and it just works, using the above we need to get it into our heads that all less files will be compiled to a specific output folder. We probably just need more experience with Gulp too :)
Thanks for helping out

Comment: Yes, in the BuildBefore.bat we have the commands for restoring npm and bower packages and also to run the gulp tasks. And yes, it changes the way you are used to because actually the result of the compilation should be injected to your webform/view with a task like gulp-inject.

Comment: So am I correct then in assuming you don't use the Task Runner Explorer bindings to bind your Gulp tasks to build events? Since you're already doing it using the BeforeBuild.bat file.

Comment: You are right, the main reason being that we need this also on our TFS build (with MSBuild).

Comment: Since last year have you come across a simpler way of achieving what your answer provided or is the only way to include bower installed files using a custom target. Also could you post the BeforeBuild.bat so we can see how you restore npm/grunt or is this no longer required in later versions of vs? my team is using vs 2015 and I want the gulp tasks to run without them having to do any manual running once they do a checkout of my project.

Answer (score 1):

For those who preferred the "Web Essentials" method of compiling Less, Sass and CoffeeScript files, Mads Kristensen has published a new VS 2015 extension named [Web Compiler](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b329021-cd7a-4a01-86fc-714c2d05bb6c?SRC=VSIDE).  Try it.  Also see his [Bundler & Minifier](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9ec27da7-e24b-4d56-8064-fd7e88ac1c40?SRC=VSIDE) extension for additional functionality removed from Web Essentials.